Kafka Clients Unable to Connect in Multi-Container Docker Network After Initial Connection (Want to Migrate to Kubernetes)
Question:
I’m running a setup with three containers in a Docker network:

MQTT Broker in one container
Apache Kafka Broker in another container (running in KRaft mode)
Python Application in a third container acting as a bridge between the MQTT broker and the Kafka broker.

The Kafka broker can successfully connect to the network initially, but after that, Kafka clients (including the Python bridge application) are unable to establish connections to Kafka.
I am looking to resolve this issue by deploying these containers using Kubernetes (K8s). Does anyone have experience with similar issues in a Docker-to-Kubernetes migration, or any insights on how to fix Kafka client connectivity in this scenario?
Things I've tried:

Ensured that the containers are all in the same Docker network.
Verified that Kafka and MQTT brokers are running correctly.
Tried using different network modes (bridge, host) in Docker.

I would appreciate any advice on potential misconfigurations, Kubernetes-specific considerations, or troubleshooting steps to resolve this Kafka connectivity issue.

Are you usign docker run --network= when you run your containers?

We created a network and are running all the containers on it.


Please show those commands 2) Kubernetes runs containers. You build those containers using Docker cli. It's not clear what you mean by migrate 3) Networking in k8s is vastly different from Docker 4) Use kafka connect rather than Python

